# Better bash script to create directory structure

Tags: regex, linux, bash, automation, mkdir

I want to create folders with plain text with a structure like:

```
Folder
| Subfolder
| | Deeper-subfolder
| Subfolder
```

I thought about using a base command like `mkdir` and found that post : [Bash script that creates a directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374382/bash-script-that-creates-a-directory-structure#answer-5374519), but it still needs to write structure like :

```
Folder
Folder/subfolder
Folder/subfolder/deeper-subfolder
Folder/subfolder
```

So I would need to change the regex used in :

```
sed '/^$/d;s/ /\//g' struct.txt | xargs mkdir -p
```

What bash command could I use to do this?

Comment: I think I get it, the top example is a file format, and you want to convert it to a set of mkdir commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using pure sed:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

x
G
: loop
s:\([^/]*\)/*\(.*\n\)\([^|]*\)|\s:\2\3\1/:
t loop

s/.*\n//
s:/*$::
h
```

For this we have to use the hold space (an auxiliary buffer) to store the previous dir path. Then we can remove directories from the hold space and replace them into the respective |s. A more detailed explanation follows:

This script is executed for every line. First thing we do is to exchange ("x") the hold space and the pattern space. Initially, the hold space will be empty, but after the first line the hold space will contain the previous directory path. By exchanging them, we load the previous directory and save the current new directory into hold space.

Next, we append the new directory name to the previous directory path (but both will be separated by newlines). The command used for this is "G".

Now we have to loop for every | character we find. To do this is the tricky part, so bear with me. Suppose we have the following in the current pattern space

```
Folder/subdir
| | deeper-subdir
```

1. Firstly, the `\([^/]*\)` matches everything before the first slash and captures it (ie. stores it in a "variable", named `\1` because it is the first capture group).
2. Then we skip slashes: `/*`
3. Capture everything up to the newline (inclusive) and store into capture `\2`: `\(.*\n\)`
4. Capture everything before the first | character and store into capture `\3`:
   `\([^|]*\)`
5. Skip the | character followed by a space character: `|\s`

Now, the captures look like this:

1. Folder
2. subdir\n
  3.

All we have to do is regenerate the lines reording the captures and adding another slash so they become:

```
subdir
Folder/| deeper-subdir
```

After that, we have a conditional branch command "t" that only banches back to the "loop" label if the previous "s" command succeeded. That means that when the string is ready (no more |s), we can exit the loop and continue with the code.

Following the example, the next iteration contains the captures:

1. subdir
2. \n
3. Folder/

After the loop, the first substitute command removes the first line, which contains the path that the new directory hasn't entered, (ie. the new directory is "shallower" than the previous one).

The last substitute command removes any slashes from the end of the line and the last command is a hold command ("h") which copies the current generated path to the hold space, so we can repeat everything for the next line.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Suppose you put this into a script mkdirs.sed, you can then call "sed -f mkdirs.sed mydirs.txt | xargs mkdir -p"

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do it with just changing regular expression in the sed script you provided. The reason is that in the example you referred to every line of the file with directory structure had enough information to create a directory. In you example you need to do some data manipulation do keep track of parent folders. This will be more complicated.. and we don't like to introduce complexity unless we have to.

Comment: I'd be tempted to do this with recursion.  For each line, recurse if you see an extra | and unwind if you see one less |.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should do it.

The idea is to maintain a "stack" of directory names and either push or pop based on how many pipes a line has.

(This script assumes that the input file is well formed and does not contain any empty lines or special characters in filenames.)

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

# helper function to create a directory from an array
mkDirs(){
    IFS=/ dir="$*"
    echo "mkdir -p $dir"
}

declare -a stack=()
while read line
do
    dirName="${line##*| }"
    pipes="${line//[^|]/}"
    num_pipes="${#pipes}"
    diff=$(( ${#stack[@]} - $num_pipes ))
    if [[ "$diff" -ne 0 ]]
    then
        # create the directory
        mkDirs "${stack[@]}"
        while (( "$diff" != 0 ))
        do
            unset stack[${#stack[@]}-1] # pop off stack
            diff=$(( ${#stack[@]} - $num_pipes ))
        done
    fi
    stack=("${stack[@]}" "$dirName") # push on stack
done < "$file"
mkDirs "${stack[@]}"
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat struct.txt
Folder
| Subfolder
| | Deeper-subfolder
| Subfolder
| | SubSubFolder
| | | Another
| | | | AnotherChild
| | | YetAnother
Folder2

$ run.sh struct.txt
mkdir -p Folder/Subfolder/Deeper-subfolder
mkdir -p Folder/Subfolder/SubSubFolder/Another/AnotherChild
mkdir -p Folder/Subfolder/SubSubFolder/YetAnother
mkdir -p Folder2
```

Comment: Seems really good, but `grep -o` gives me an error `Grep: invalid option -o`.

Comment: updated to use pure bash to count the number of pipes instead of `grep -o`.